# Compressing a file in python and keep the grammar exact when opening it again

Tags: python

I'm trying to find some code for my course work and I can't for the life of me find any. I need a piece of code that I can use that will compress a text file in Python, and then can be opened again while keeping all of the grammar in the exact same place? Any help would be great. Thanks :)

Comment: Use any of https://docs.python.org/3/library/archiving.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. Hope it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import zlib, base64
text = 'STACK OVERFLOW'
code =  base64.b64encode(zlib.compress(text,9))
print code
```

which gives :

```
eNoLDnF09lbwD3MNcvPxD1cIHhxcAE9UKaU=
```

Now I can copy this code to a different program to get the original program back:

```
import zlib, base64
s='eNoLDnF09lbwD3MNcvPxD1cIHhxcAE9UKaU='
data = zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode(s))
print data
```

Answer (score 0):

```
T = 'blah blah blah blah'
S = zlib.compress(T)
with open("temp.zlib", "wb") as myfile:
    myfile.write(S)
```

This saves the compressed string in a file called temp.zlib so that program 2 can later retrieve and decompress it.

Program 2:

```
with open("temp.zlib", "rb") as myfile:
    S = myfile.read()
T = zlib.decompress(S)
```